# Laravel 5.2 - Every route redirects to the homepage

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I just started an laravel 5.2 application. Every route I take (/register, /logout, login,...) redirects me to the homepage.

Here are my **routes**

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
//Register
    Route::get('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::get('/register/success', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegisterSuccess');

    Route::post('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@PostRegister');

//Login
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');

    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@PostLogin');

//Password Reset
    Route::get('/password/reset/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
    Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getToken');
    Route::get('/password/reset/sent', 'Auth\PasswordController@getSent');

    Route::post('/password/reset/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
    Route::post('/password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
});


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

when I remove the `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {` line I can access the page but it gives me the error of

> Undefined variable: errors

That's why the web middelware is required, So I'm kinda stuck.

The controller and views work. It's just this redirect that I can't figure out.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your route which return `welcome` page must be before other routes

Answer (score 2):

You need to make changes in your AuthController and put where do you want to be redirected.

Then you need to add this in every controller you have:

```
public function __construct() { $this->middleware('auth'); }
```

Comment: Tried that, but without any result.

Comment: this worked! Can briefly explain what it exactly it does? Thanks!

Comment: Like every construct function, whenever you use controller, this function will be automatically called. It means that you are logged in and that you can use that method from that route. Im sry for my bad eng, i hope that you understand

Comment: At first the answer wasn't clear enough, but in the comment you really clearly solved the issue. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a blade template like auth.blade.php in resources/views.  Then you need to make the view from your controller with a return like:

```
   public function getLogin(){
        return view(
            "auth",
            [
                'username' => username,
                'password' => password
            ]
        );
}
```