# Can't get stock auth controller to work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Auth controller keeps redirecting me back to home page. A Session is setting fine. I am using cookies as the driver.

A Session Cookie is being set, but Session Storage, viewed with Chrome Developer Tools, is empty.

It redirects fine, if I comment out the redirect()->guest('/'); in middleware. It means that it keeps authenticating as guest and if I var_dump(Auth::user()); I get NULL.

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548061/laravel-5-2-auth-not-working/34548115#34548115)

Comment: ^ already using the middle-ware 'web'. Before, using the web middle-ware, session cookie was not being set. However, this problem is solved now. Still, for some reason, the session doesn't seem to be persisting.

Comment: What exactly Laravel version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this. I answered it in another question here:

[Laravel 5.2 - Every route redirects to the homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201910/laravel-5-2-every-route-redirects-to-the-homepage/36203256#36203256)

Comment: I have a redirect route defined in auth controller. The redirect works fine, however, the session is not persisting. It considers the user as guest and redirects him back to homepage. If I disable the guest redirection, it redirects fine to my dashboard. However, in that case there is no session, because the user is guest.

Comment: I meant this comment: "
Try to add this in every controller you have: public function __construct() { $this->middleware('auth'); } "

Comment: Maybe you didnt used middleware in a proper way: Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {  
  // put your routes here
 });